# Bindings in Guice: Compile time dependencies

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

While exploring Guice, I had a question on the way the dependencies are injected.

Based on my understanding, one of the important aspects of DI is that, the dependency is known and is injected at runtime.

In Guice, to inject a dependency we either need to add the binding or implement a provider. Adding a dependency takes a class object which adds a compile time dependency on that class. One way to avoid that is to implement it as a provider and let the provider use reflection to dynamic load the class.

```
public class BillingModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).toProvider(
            BofACreditCardProcessorProvider.class);
    bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).annotatedWith(BofA.class).toProvider(
            BofACreditCardProcessorProvider.class);
    bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).annotatedWith(Amex.class).toProvider(
            AmexCreditCardProcessorProvider.class);
}

@Provides
PaymentProcessor createPaymentProcessor() {
    return new PayPalPaymentProcessor();
}

@Provides
PayPalPaymentProcessor createPayPalPaymentProcessor() {
    return new PayPalPaymentProcessor();
}}
```

Is there a reason why Guice choose class object over class name? That could have removed the compile time dependency right?

Comment: Honestly, i did not get it. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @MilanBaran okay, let me try it again. say there are three components A, B and C. C requires an implementation of A and B. thats were we inject the implementation of A & B to C. now imagine there is a maven module M1 which wants to inject an implementation of A and B but they are owned by other maven module M2. to inject the implementations, module M should have a compile dependency on module M2.

Comment: spring uses XML as one of the approaches to support this. you can specify the implementor in the XML. this link [link](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-dependency-injection-with-xml-example) has an example of such config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your **interface** and **implementation** are defined in the same dependency (that is, in the same JAR file) then you already have a hard build dependency on the implementation, whether you use Guice or not.

Basically, as soon as you have:

```
public final class MyClass {
  public void doSomething(Foo foo);
}
```

Then to compile `MyClass` a definition of `Foo` needs to be on the compile-time classpath.

The way to resolve this is to separate out the interface from the implementation. For example, if `Foo` is an interface, and `FooImpl` is the implementation of it, you would put `FooImpl` in a different dependency (that is, a different JAR file) from `Foo`.

Now, let's say you have two sub-projects in Maven:

```
foo-api/
  pom.xml
  src/main/java/com/foo/Foo.java

foo-impl/
  pom.xml
  src/main/java/com/foo/FooImpl.java
```

Where should the Guice module that binds `Foo` live? It shouldn't live in the `foo-api` project, it should live in the `foo-impl` project, alongside `FooImpl`.

Now suppose you have a separate implementation of `Foo` (let's call it `SuperFoo`), and your project needs a `Foo`, but it could be either `FooImpl` or `SuperFoo`.

If we make `SuperFoo` its own project:

```
super-foo/
  pom.xml
  src/main/java/com/super/foo/SuperFoo.java
  src/main/java/com/super/foo/SuperFooModule.java
```

Now all your application code can simply `@Inject Foo` and use the foo. In your `main()` method (or wherever you create your `Injector`) you need to decide whether to install `FooModule` (from `foo-impl`) or `SuperFooModule` (from `super-foo`).

**That** is the place where reflection may be warranted. For example, you could have a configuration flag `foo_module` which could be set to either `"com.foo.FooModule"` or `"com.super.foo.SuperFooModule"`. You could decide which one to install using code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Config config = parseConfig(args);
  List<Module> modules = new ArrayList<>();
  modules.add(...); // application modules

  String fooModuleName = config.get("foo_module");
  Class<? extends Module> moduleClass =
      Class.forName(fooModuleName).asSubclass(Module.class);
  modules.add(moduleClass.newInstance());

  Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(modules);
  injector.getInstance(MyApplication.class).run();
}
```

Of course, you could also use any other mechanism you like to select which module to install. In many cases, you don't even really want to do this reflectively, you can simply change the code at the same time you change the build dependency.

Comment: Okay, this make sense. We can always have the module in the implementation. Where even we want to override some implementation, we implement it using appropriate annotation and create a new module out of it. You are basically proposing to load the modules dynamically as opposed to loading the implementations.